# How to use TaskExecutorService discarding overlapping task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have a scenario of running 2 separate standalone  java polling tool where it would run some specific task with a fixed interval of 5 minutes.

MY scenario is (for each polling service):

1) if a task T0 is required more than 5 minutes to run and meanwhile  after 5 minutes  T5 comes and tries to execute , i would discard it, not wait,or relaunch (Discard overlapping tasks)

2) The next task would start at T10 normally.

My question is is using Quartz will be an overkill ? I f I use TaskExecutorService how can I check on time X that once task started on time X-5 is already running and I should discard it.

Note:
1) I must use JDK <= 6.0

2) I am not using  under any framework like spring.

3) its an desktop tool so I need to launch it and it would run..

Any code snippet or direction is appreciated.

UPDATED for the answer of the comment below:

Yes its between tasks running in a single tool. The tools are different, there is no connection between the tools,they will run separately and has no relation.

a single tool runs a same task in a 5 minutes interval (like every file minute it looks inside a directory for files and if found parses those files and works with them).

If ,say for an example once the task is currently running started from first minute (it may take any amount of time), after 5 minutes the tool launches that task again looking for new files, but this time it will not parse/work with it, as a previous task is already running processing some files.so the new task will not execute and the system will dump it(NO queue/ no waiting / no sequential jobs ).

Another new task will again run on 5x time and if no other is running it will parse and process those files.

Comment: when you say discard a task, is it between tasks running in a single tool ? and why do you need to discard it? are you having different tasks? if you have the same task running on the 5 min interval, will be good for you to guarantee that a task run 5 mins after the first has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the reply on the question in the comment, you can use [Excecutors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to obtain a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Then, you can use the method [scheduleWithFixedDelay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) to submit your task. This method reruns the task with a delay between the runs. The good thing for your case is that the delay counting starts after the current run finishes. This will give you what you want without using a boolean variable or a ReentrantLock as you will not have two tasks running at the same time. You just need to be careful to catch exceptions as an exception will cause subsequent runs of the task to be cancelled.

So lets assume you have a class MyTask which implements runnable

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable{

  public void run() {
     try {
           //your task code here
     } catch (...) {
        //deal with the exceptions here               
     }
  }

}
```

assuming you will run from main method, you can now use the class to schedule the reoccurring task:

```
public class TaskRunner{

private static final ScheduledExecutorService taskScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyTask(),0,5,TimeUnit.MINUTES);  
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this code no task is overlapping and only one task is running at a time, and the new one starts after 5 minutes . But now the question has come to me is, the next 5 minutes starts after the previous one finishes. Not the original 5 min interval. Like, if the first one starts at 10:00 AM and finishes at 10:07, the next one starts at 10:12 and not in  10:10 as at 10:05 the system should do nothing and passes on. Is that possible ? Otherwise I will stick to current solution.

Comment: The code above makes the same behavior that you mentioned. if one starts at 10 and finishes at 10:07, the next starts at 10:12. if the one starting at 10:12 runs for 3 minutes and finishes at 10:15, the next starts at 10:20. and so on. you can make a test and print the time in each task start and end to see what is happening to make sure of that.

Comment: also note: there are no new tasks submitted in the middle. it is the same task that gets rescheduled. so there is no task starting at 10:10 in the scenario you gave. the task starts and finishes, and then gets rescheduled to run again 5 mins after that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5, min). Declare a common boolean variable `isRunning=false`. Each task checks this variable at the start, and if it is set already, exits, otherwise sets it to true and runs. At the end, sets it to false. Checking and setting should be done in a synchronized block.